# Having a git repository in a git repository but only one remote

Tags: git, heroku, github

I'm currently working on my bachelor's thesis where I want to implement a specific app using four different web frameworks as a comparison. I want to put all projects in a git repository and host it on github.

The problem is that each project should be a git repository as well so I can push and deploy them to Heroku.

Is it possible to have these nested git repositories with one parent repository which I push on github?

I had a look at git submodules but it seemed that this way each project needs to be a separate repository on github aswell.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.
However, with the unofficial [heroku buildpack monorepo](https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-buildpack-monorepo), you can have a single GIT repository and multiple apps within it.

You would have one remote per app, and specify within that app's config vars which subfolder to use.
Whenever you deploy, the repository will move the app from the subfolder into the main one, and remove all the other ones.